# Enabling/disabling a PID loop via FSM in a microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, control, pid-controller

I have a PID loop for a small vehicle implemented in a microcontroller. Currently the PID loop is implemented in a timer interrupt. I want to implement an FSM that will have states that enable or disable the function that the PID loop is controlling, so in some states the PID loop should be disabled and in some it's enabled. I want to implement this control in a way that minimally disturbs the PID loop.

I've been told that I shouldn't disable the timer interrupt if possible. Is a good option for this to implement the FSM itself inside of the timer interrupt and then update the PID loop inside the FSM states?

The alternative would be to have just the PID loop inside the timer interrupt and then the FSM implemented inside the microcontroller's `main()`, which I think would need to temporarily enable or disable the timer loop while updating state.

Comment: There's really not enough here to answer this.  Generally consider that *enabling* the PID is fairly distinct from its operation and probably safely asynchronous, eg, at a given instant you can either drive output or you can't, and presumably the loop itself can't modify that.  So you could run this FSM in the ISR, or you could actually run it in the main as long as the operation of assigning the value is itself atomic, which it typically would be if the state variable were no larger than the processor memory word size...

Comment: Although not strictly a necessity, you might find greater clarity in sharing with the ISR only a boolean flag that indicates enabled or not, and not the actual state variable.  Though again, strictly speaking, there is no logic hazard as long as the size of the FSM state word is comparable or smaller to the CPU memory width and aligned with it.

Answer (score 0):

As Chris says, there's not enough information to give a concise answer.
Your 'pid loop' - more correctly your 'pid controller' could be running 1 million times per second or only once per second. Then there's the timing criticality of it - does it need to run in the timer isr? If the processing varies +/- 100us is that an issue?
Then there's the FSM. FSM is just a concept - it depends on your actual implementation. It might take 1us to execute or 10seconds.

So what technique you use to solve you problem depends on your constraints - time, processing, code size etc. The more operations you pour into your timer isr, the more is stolen from the mainline code and other interrupt sources. As well, you can't have 1.5ms of operations in a 1ms timer tick - you can try, but the outcome won't be favourable.

Determine your constraints - be it requirements or measuring execution time etc and let the numbers guide you.
The outcome might dictate a certain strategy, or it might be that you can choose an number of different strategies each with much the same outcome. No problem is the same - if they were, then we wouldn't need engineers.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're talking about a mechanical positioning or speed control loop, so probably sample rate will be in the hundreds of Hz.

Any FSM is likely going to take negligible time compared to calculating the PID output, so I think I'd combine the two.

Keep in mind that switching PID on/off requires some care as to the initial conditions to provide "bumpless" control.